# Im trying to determine how to do a multi level count

Tags: sql-server

I am relatively new to SQL, and I'm probably overlooking a simple answer.

For example, I have a table with the following columns

CustomerID

Hair_Color

Eye_Color

Skin_Color

Braces (Y/N)

---

I want 4 counts of unique CustomerIDs

1. I want a count of those that are blonde
2. Then I want a count of all those that have blue eyes, but if they were blonde, I don’t want them included
3. Then I want a count of all those that are Caucasian, but if they were blonde or had blue eyes, I don’t want them included
4. Then I want a count of all those with braces, but if they were blonde, had blue eyes, or were Caucasian, I don’t want them included.

Comment: It's nice that you want them, but SO is not a code-writing service. Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will make sure to include that next time.

Answer (score 2):

CASE Statements to the rescue:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE when hair_color = 'blonde' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as blondes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN eye_color = 'blue' and hair_color <> 'blonde' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Blue_eyed_non_blondes',
    etc..
FROM table
```